# Recaptcha translation of labels

Tags: translation, recaptcha

I am building custom recaptcha theme according to [API documentation](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/customization). In the html I have:

```
<span class="recaptcha_only_if_image">Enter the words above:</span>
<span class="recaptcha_only_if_audio">Enter the numbers you hear:</span>
<input type="text" id="recaptcha_response_field" name="recaptcha_response_field" />
```

I am using several locales and I am setting them like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var RecaptchaOptions = {
   lang : 'fr'
};
</script>
```

This translates most of the recaptcha but obviously it won't translate the "**Enter the words above:**" label I shown above. I know that the default recaptcha has all the translations for the labels. My question is: can I somehow get those translations and apply them dynamically so I don't have to store them on the server side?

**EDIT:**

I found the solution myself with help of jQuery and inspecting the recaptcha js objects in FireBug:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var current_locale = RecaptchaOptions['lang']
var translations = window['RecaptchaStr_' + current_locale]
$('span.recaptcha_only_if_image').text(translations['instructions_visual']);
$('span.recaptcha_only_if_audio').text(translations['instructions_audio']);
</script>
```

Hope this helps someone else.

Answer (score 0):

place this after the `<head>`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var RecaptchaOptions = {
   lang : 'fr',
};
</script>
```

before the `<form>` element where reCAPTCHA appears

**update**
i think you are  seeking for a translation service  you can refer some of the below

### Translate API's

---

[Google Translate API](http://code.google.com/apis/language/translate/overview.html)
[Tut: How to Use Google Translate API](http://rupeshpatel.wordpress.com/2012/06/23/usage-of-google-translator-api-for-free/)

[Yandex Translation API](http://api.yandex.com/translate/)
[Mygengo Translation API](http://mygengo.com/api/)
[Microsoft Translator APIs](http://www.microsofttranslator.com/dev/)
[Speaklite Translate API](http://www.speaklike.com/access-professional-translation-via-api/)
[WebServiceX Translate API](http://www.webservicex.net/ws/wsdetails.aspx?wsid=63)

Comment: That's not really the issue here. I want to get the specific translation for "Enter the words above" from recaptcha servers. As I said I am creating custom theme and setting the locale like that only translates the text in audio mode that is generated dynamically. The labels I pasted are static html.